# New to writing batch files, but need help constructing one to search for and delete all subfolders of a specific name

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I need a simple batch file that can search my "F:\Temp" directory with multiple folders (of various names), for subfolders named "Subs", and delete them, along with any files the "Subs" folders may contain. Using similar asked questions on here, I've constructed the below script, but it doesn't seem to be finding the "Subs" folders within the directory.

```
for /f %%i in ("F:\Temp\***\Subs") do rd /s "%%~i"
```

Its important to note, I don't know what `/f %%i` does, along with the `%%~i`. Also, I'm not sure my wildcard is setup properly. Just to be clear, the folders directly below `F:\Temp` are of various names, and have no similarities. The only thing I want to find and delete are subfolders named `Subs` within these variously named folders in `F:\Temp`.

Comment: I just realized I forgot the "\" before *** in my working script. Please ignore this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to delete subdirectories named `Subs` within directories in `F:\Temp`

The following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d f:\Temp
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b /s Subs') do (
  echo "%%i"
  rem rd /s "%%i"
  )
```

Check the output and then remove the `rem` before `rd` if it is matching the correct subdirectories.

> I don't know what `/f %%i` does

It is the arguments to a `for` command.

> The operation of the FOR command can be summarised as...
>
> - Take a set of data
> - Make a `FOR` Parameter `%%G` equal to some part of that data
> - Perform a command (optionally using the parameter as part of the command).
> - Repeat for each item of data

See [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for a full explanation

> along with the `%%~i`

This make no sense

> I'm not sure my wildcard `F:\Temp\***\Subs` is setup properly

You can't have wildcards in the middle of a subdirectory name. They have to be at the end.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `For /R [Folder] /D`:

```bath
@echo off

for /r "F:\Temp" /d %%i in (*Subs
    )do echo\%%~nxi & rmdir /s /q "%%~dpnxi"
```

---

---

**Obs.:** To ensure that the folder to be removed is with the strings `\Subs` and not another one containing the string `subs` in the name, I recommend doing a filter with the `| find "\Strings"`:

```bath
for...()do echo\%%~dpi%%~nxi | find /i "\Subs" && run rd ...
```

- Your bat will only remove the folders if found in the path and name of the `\Subs` strings, and your
  batch would look like this:

```bath
@echo off

for /r "F:\Temp" /d %%i in (*Subs)do (
     echo\%%~dpi%%~nxi | find /i "\Subs" && rd /s /q "%%~dpnxi"
    )
```

---

---

What can and will help in many commands would be to familiarizing yourself with:

---

```bath
For
For /r 
For /d
For loop expanding variables
```

---

- Using a `For`loop you can expand your variable:

```bath
    %~i   - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fi  - expands %i to a fully qualified path file/dir name only
    %~ni  - expands %i to a file/dir name only
    %~xi  - expands %i to a file/dir extension only
    
    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file/dir name and extension
```

- ```bath
  Use the FOR variable syntax replacement:
      %~pi        - expands %i to a path only
      %~ni        - expands %i to a file name only
      %~xi        - expands %i to a file extension only
  ```
- ```bath
  The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
      %~pni       - expands %i to a path and file name only
      %~pnxi      - expands %i to a path, file name and extension only
  ```

**Obs**.: About using **`%%~nxi`** in `directory` name observation note in **`ss64.com`**:

- ```bath
  Full Stop Bug
  Although Win32 will not recognise any file or directory name that begins or ends 
     with a '.' (period/full stop) it is possible to include a Full Stop in the middle
     of a directory name and this can cause issues with FOR /D.
  ```
- ```bath
  Parameter expansion will treat a Full Stop as a file extension, so for a directory
  name like "Sample 2.6.4" the output of %%~nI will be truncated to "Sample 2.6" to
  return the whole folder name use %%I or %%~nxI
  ```

---

With `for /d` all directories will be listed in the loop, and their source names will be in `%%~nxi`, which can be used in the `echo\%%~nxi & rmdir /s /q "%%~dpnxi"` command syntax.

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
  - **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**